# CV2: Approximating Moments/Single Contour return

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I am currently trying to get contours of a collection of images. But CV2 is unable to return the full contours for various images as shown below.

[image]

Hence, I am looking for a way to either approximate the moments for the list of contours, a way to make CV2 return a single contour when calling the function "findContours(...)" or merge the list of contours returned into a single contour if possible.
My codes(Updated) currently consists of:

```
def find_if_close(cnt1,cnt2):
    row1,row2 = cnt1.shape[0],cnt2.shape[0]
    for i in range(row1):
        for j in range(row2):
            dist = np.linalg.norm(cnt1[i]-cnt2[j])
            if abs(dist) < 50 :
                return True
            elif i==row1-1 and j==row2-1:
                return False

def thresh_callback(thresh, img, gray, blur):
    edges = cv2.Canny(blur,thresh,thresh*2)
    drawing = np.zeros(img.shape,np.uint8)                  # Image to draw the contours
    image, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    LENGTH = len(contours)
    status = np.zeros((LENGTH,1))

    for i,cnt1 in enumerate(contours):
        x = i    
        if i != LENGTH-1:
            for j,cnt2 in enumerate(contours[i+1:]):
                x = x+1
                dist = find_if_close(cnt1,cnt2)
                if dist == True:
                    val = min(status[i],status[x])
                    status[x] = status[i] = val
                else:
                    if status[x]==status[i]:
                        status[x] = i+1

    unified = []
    maximum = int(status.max())+1
    for i in range(maximum):
        pos = np.where(status==i)[0]
        if pos.size != 0:
            cont = np.vstack(contours[i] for i in pos)
            unified.append(cont)

   cv2.drawContours(img,unified,-1,(0,255,0),2)
   cv2.drawContours(drawing,unified,-1,255,-1)

   cv2.imshow('output',img)
   cv2.imshow('input',drawing)
   cv2.waitKey(0)
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()

   return moments, cx, cy, count

def alter_image(img, blur):
    ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(blur, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    bitwise = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh1)
    erosion = cv2.erode(bitwise, np.ones((2, 2) ,np.uint8), iterations=1) #15
    dilation = cv2.dilate(erosion, np.ones((3, 3) ,np.uint8), iterations=1) #45
    return dilation

imgs = cv2.imread('./images/'+str(num)+'.jpg')
img_grey = cv2.cvtColor(imgs,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_grey,(5,5),0)
imgs = alter_image(imgs, blur)
thresh = 255
max_thresh = 255

moments, cx, cy, count = thresh_callback(thresh, imgs, img_grey, blur)
```

As shown in the codes, I tried to alter the image through changes such as erosion, dilation, bitwise changes but the results were still the same.The original image can be found below.
[image]

Image Output (Updated):
[image]

Comment: The image is too small I cant see it. However, there are infinite solutions to your problem, you may need to find a criteria to minimize, i.e. the single contour that has all the contours conected with the minimum extra line, or the one that is smooth on its second derivative, or something else

Comment: After reading your comment I decided to use the contour with the largest area using cv2.contourArea(..) is this considered a valid way or criteria for handling the issue? Sorry I'm actually new to this and don't really know what is right or wrong. @AnderBiguri

Comment: Can you show better where is the contour not continous? Again, I can not see it in the first image, its too small

Comment: I have added a larger image output, I hope that is what your looking for. In my codes i drew the center of mass point using a red dot for each contour. @AnderBiguri

Comment: You say "I am currently trying to get contours of a collection of images. But CV2 is unable to return the full contours for various images as shown below." I still see a full contour

Comment: It's because I looped and drew each and every cnt using `for cnt in contours:` from the list of contours returned by `image, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`. But I'm hoping to find a way to reduce this to a single "cnt", as I am trying to keep a single moments as a feature for my data analysis and can't have multiple moments for a single image entry. @AnderBiguri

Comment: If this is the case, it just looks like your contours are discontinuous for very small breaks (a pixel wide or so). Can you program some easy algorithm, such as:  if there are more than one contour, get endpoints of contours and match them for minimal distance, finally making a single contour out of it. This works as long as the errors you are expecting are like in this one, where piecewise contours are just very very close to each other

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I went to look for codes and adjusted them to suit my needs but there seems to be a tiny error. Could you have  a quick look to see what the problem is? @AnderBiguri

Comment: You have clearly not matched them by the shortest distance! You just matched them *if the distance is close*. Just find the closest one. 1) Get all endpoints. 2)match them by distance 3) close the contour on matched poitns